# Array_intersect returns NULL

Tags: php, woocommerce, array-intersect

i'm trying to compare array1_ids with the cart of a customer if products of the array match those in the cart field x_name should be there if not it
should be gone.
I get the values from my cart and array1_ids but when I put them through the array_intersect it will result in NULL causing it to always return true.

Here is my code:

```
function wc_ninja_product_is_in_the_cart() {
/*array 1*/
$array1_ids = array( '1', '3', '5');//field that should
/*array 2*/
//$micro_ids = array( '2', '4');//fields that shouldnt come back

    // Products currently in the cart
    $cart_ids = array();
    $cart_categories = array();

    // Find each product in the cart and add it to the $cart_ids array
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $cart_product = $values['data'];
        $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
    }

    // If one of the special products are in the cart, return true.
    if ( ! array_intersect($array1_ids, $cart_ids) ) {
        echo "true: " , implode(';',$cart_ids);;//bug fixing
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        echo "false: " , implode(';',$cart_ids);;//bug fixing
    }
}
//Field Remover
function wc_ninja_remove_checkout_field( $fields ) {
    if ( ! wc_ninja_product_is_in_the_cart() )    {
        //removes Field x_name
        unset( $fields['billing']['x_name'] );
    }
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'wc_ninja_remove_checkout_field' );
```

Comment: Are you sure `$card_ids` has elements?

Comment: everything returns values unless you run them through the array_intersect()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$hasSpecialProduct= false;    
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $cart_product = $values['data'];
    if (in_array($cart_product->id, $array1_ids)) {
        $hasSpecialProduct = true;
    }
    $cart_ids[]   = $cart_product->id;
}

// If one of the special products are in the cart, return true.
if ( $hasSpecialProduct ) {
    echo "true: " , implode(';',$cart_ids);;//bug fixing
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

you can make the last part shorter:

```
return $hasSpecialProduct;
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! I can not upvote since I am new on stack overflow but thanks anyway. I've accepted your answer anyway.